# Export specific data from a selected cell's row into a CSV file

Tags: vba, excel, csv, export-to-csv

I have been searching for a solution to this, but it seems like I cannot find it.
So basically, I want to select e.g. H2 and then run the macro.
Then it should copy/paste some specific cells into a new CSV file, e.g. O2 and F2. I also want a fixed value that should always be there, called "No".

The first row of the CSV file should be "UTF-8". The next (2nd row in the CSV) should be some headers that is fixed, just as the UTF-8.

**Could a solution be to copy all the relevant data into another sheet with the proper format, and then just export that sheet as a CSV?**

*Illustration:*

```
"UTF-8"
"Name","ID","Email","Customer"
"H2","O2","F2","No"
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Hi guys, sorry my late reply, I have been busy. I think I can solve this with a `For Each selection` loop and using the following `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("XX:XX").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("XX")` .. I will see how it turns out tomorrow and post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution ended up being exporting the correct data into another sheet with the proper setup, using the following.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("XX:XX").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("XX")
```